# Create an errorHandler to handle all error cases with Express js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have created an errorMiddleware class in my Nodejs api :

```
const { appLogger } = require('../utils/logger');
const { getENVValue } = require('../utils/fonction');
const CustomException = require('../utils/CustomException');

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {

const error = (err.isHandled === undefined) ? new CustomException(500, 'ERR_UNKNOWN', err.stack.replace(/ {4}/g, "").split('\n').slice(1), false) : err;
    const errorResponseBody = (getENVValue('ENV') === 'LOCAL') ? error.errorMessage : error.errorKey;

    if (!error.isHandled) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    appLogger.error(JSON.stringify(error.errorMessage));
    res.status(error.statusCode).send(errorResponseBody);
}
```

The goal is to handle all the error that happened during the execution of the request. But I don't understand why sometimes it doesn't works. For example, here are my index.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { getENVValue } = require('./src/utils/fonction');
const routes = require('./src/routes/routes');
const requestLogMiddleware = require('./src/middlewares/request-log-middleware');
const authenticationMiddleware = require('./src/middlewares/authentication-middleware');
const errorMiddleware = require('./src/middlewares/error-middleware');

const port = getENVValue('PORT');

app.use(requestLogMiddleware);
app.use(authenticationMiddleware);

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', routes);

app.use(errorMiddleware);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

My routes.js file :

```
const express = require('express');
const CustomException = require('../utils/CustomException');
const { createJWT } = require('../utils/authentication');
const usersRoutes = require('./users-routes');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/users', usersRoutes);

router.get('', (req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).send({});
});

router.get('/error', (req, res, next) => {
    throw new CustomException(410, 'ERR_UNKNOWN', 'Message quelconque');
})

router.get('/unhandled-error', (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('Message quelconque');
})

module.exports = router;
```

And my users-routes.js file :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const CustomException = require('../utils/CustomException');

router.get('/:user_id', async (req, res, next)=>{
    const user_id = req.params.user_id;
    //TODO request to db
    throw new CustomException(404, 'ERR_UNKNOWN_USER', `This user_id: doesn't refer to an existing user.`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I request the /error or /unhandled-error the customException is used. However when i request the route /users/1 or whatever after the /, it doesn't call the customException.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use that is to create a middleware function [as defined in the express documentation.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers)

Please note this important sentence:

> You define error-handling middleware **last**, after other app.use() and routes calls

(emphasis is my own)

Comment: As you can see in my index.js file I already have defined an app.use(errorMiddleware); whereas it doesn't work.